# How would you import 22.000 products to Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, import

I'm working on a Magento store and I'm looking to import 22.000 products with a single solution.

I've written a Ruby wrapper for the REST API, it takes around 7 seconds to create a single product (visible in store, assigned to a product category, assigned to website and with one image)

The Ruby wrapper for the REST API is tested against a demo Magento store hosted on a DigitalOcean VPS with 2 CPU'S and 2GB RAM.

It would take a very long time to import the 22.000 with a single solution using the Ruby wrapper.

Since I'm not a very experienced programmer and don't have PHP or SQL knowledge, I'm wondering how a more experienced programmer would solve this.

Comment: What reindexing issues?

Comment: @Serpyre What do you suggest for data maintenance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the best way is using MAGMI. you can find that open source project in the following url http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/ . The tutorial of how to use it -> http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page .

Magmi’s speed is very evident whenever you import a large number of SKUs. We’ve seen import speeds of as many as 2-3,000 products per minute. The speed depends on such things as the number of fields to be imported and whether images are imported from the same server or from remote URLs.

You can also build scripts to automatically run that could pull a file from a remote server and update the products using a cron job.

Comment: Also [Danslo API Import](https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport) is a good system to use too.

Comment: do you know if it works with magento2?

Comment: I have no clue. I saw some bits in the repo about mage2 but I don't know where it is at currently.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I cannot share any performance insights, but [AvS_FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) is also a good way to import a lot of products in a nice and performant way. It makes the whole import process a bit more comfortable, because it is based on arrays. There is also a good [documentation](https://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/) available. So you may want to have a look at it, too.