# How to Import bulk products (60000+) to magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv, magmi

I am having a list of 60000 products and I want to import them to magento website using csv.
I have created the csv file by exporting a fake product from magento and then inserted the required data to them.
I used import feature of Magento but it was taking too much time.
So I have created the bunch of 500 products to import at a time but after importing 9-10 times i.e. 5000 products, its taking too much time.
Is there any way to import products very fast?

Please suggest me. I have tried to use Magmi but did not able to do with this.
As I am new to Magento please explain the solution in detail will be highly appreciable.

Comment: the best way is magmi. check my answer here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33419/how-would-you-import-22-000-products-to-magento/33420#33420

Comment: If you have a problem using magmi you can try to open a question here and describe what your problem is, but because we don't support third party modules here, probably it gets closed. The alternative is to open a question in the new magento forum http://community.magento.com/